# spark checkpoint files processed

Tags: apache-spark

I am creating spark streaming app. Basically it shall read files from HDFS folder (which can be pretty huge), do a transformation (using sliding window) and save output to HDFS. I am struggling to find a way to checkpoint files which were already processed. `FileInputDStream` itself tracks previously processed files via `recentlySelectedFiles` to decide if given file/files shall be processed in current batch,  but `recentlySelectedFiles` seems it is not serializable... 
Is there anyway to "mark" already processed files so when job is restarted it will start processing files which were uploaded a the time the job was down skipping already processed files...